# (Apex) Pop a message when input done and click save

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
    <apex:inputText size="36" value="{!Str}"/>
    <apex:commandButton onClick="alert('{!Str}');" value="Alert"/>
</apex:form>
```

The code is just to pop out an alert window to display the input. However, it seems not a possible to do so with Salesforce apex since it's a server-side language. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fou new value of str you nead select it by javaScript or jQuery.

apex:inputText styleClass="str" value="{!Str}"

'alert($('.str').value())'

Comment: Solved. Thanks.
It's what it needs to display the message.